# Coding firmware/kernel for windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

My girlfriend has an windows phone 8 Lumia 720. She recently lost her phone. The person who robbed changed the SIM card and we was unable to locate it (but we could found previously and we almost called the police).

I would like to develop a custom kernel for the phone developed by myself.

I need this feature to ensure that this phone won't be robbed and if so, we could locate even if the phone has been reseted.

How can I accomplish that? Do you have any ideas, tutorials, guide or stuff like that?

Can I create and install native drivers for WP8 (as workaround)?

**UPDATE**

I have found some sources

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-interop-unlock-nokia-lumia-710-800-flash-a-custom-rom/

Once I have unlocked the phone I could create/modify the drivers for auto-run an app for geo-positioning & tracking. I could change the recover area to do the same even if the phone reset.

They're trying do that @xda... so I guess this post is wrong located.

Comment: Good luck on writing that w/o hardware specs. Android-based devices at least use linux kernel, which is a nice start for modifications; writing a kernel from scratch is a few *thousand* man-hours

Comment: Actually, it's even harder than that. Windows Phone 8 is based on Windows 8 kernel and use the secure boot protection. So you would have to bypass the protection first. Only OEMs are allowed to develop firmwares/drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public information on how to do what you are asking.

The public SDKs and documentation are for writing sandboxed applications that have no way of overwriting the behaviour of the OS.

If you really want to write your own kernel you'll need to look at using different OS/Hardware.